# How can I pass a 'function with parameters' as a parameter when the types and argument length may differ?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a basic synchronous task scheduler in C++ for my application.The way I am thinking to do this is to treat every task as a `Task` object, and then the `TaskScheduler` can operate on them rather than handling multiple types.

```
class Task {
public:
    Task( ... ? /* some sort of callback function stored in the task which is called at a later time*/) {}

    virtual void Execute() = 0;
}
```

The `Task` will be responsible for storing what happens on each task and I am thinking to pass a function to either the constructor of the `Task` object, or the execution but here is where I am stuck. 
For example if I had two tasks `IntegerTask : Task` and `StringTask : Task` and their callback functions looked like `func(int, int, int)` and `func(std::string)` respectively.

How can I pass these functions to the base task when the arguments might differ in lengths and the types of each parameter may change depending on which task has been created?

I don't want the `TaskScheduler` to be coupled with anything outside of its class, as such it should be able to operate on its own without any dependencies. Please ask if there is any clarification needed, I tried to explain as best as I could. Is this even possible in C++ or is there a better solution for what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Thank you for the reply. So they're not normally supposed to run with any parameters?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Oh wow, that's exactly what I was looking for then! I'll give this a try and see how it works out

Comment: Why do you want to pass a function with unknown parameter list? You cannot call it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of providing a complex class with virtual calls, use `std::function<void()>` in association with lambdas:

```
class Task
{
    std::function<void()> task;
public:
    Task(std::function<void()> task):task(std::move(task)){}

    void execute() {task();}
};
```

Then to create a task with different "types", just do:

```
std::string foo = "foo";

Task task1([=]() {  foo.size(); } );
task1.execute();

int bar = 0;

Task task2([=]() {  bar; } );
task2.execute();
```

Be aware that I'm using `[=]` here. This copies the required values int he lambdas, so that I don't have to deal with object lifetime. If you know the object always exists, you can use `[&]` or a combination of the two.